# After installing last ubuntu patches then Virtualbox don't work even I cannot unistalled

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox, crash

I have installed the last update I receive for my ubuntu 22.04
Then Virtualbox could not start my VM
I get this message:

```
he VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing
```

trying to reinstall virtualbox-dkms i get an error.
I decide to remove Virtual box but I cannot uninstall above package.

Can someone give me some hint on how to solve this issue?

I see the following crash report:

```
root@Spike:~# cat /var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash 
ProblemType: Package
DKMSBuildLog:
 DKMS make.log for virtualbox-6.1.38 for kernel 6.5.0-14-generic (x86_64)
 zo 14 jan 2024 18:03:08 CET
 make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic'
 warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
   The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
   You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvGip.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/SUPLibAll.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/powernotification-r0drv.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/assert-r0drv-linux.o
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o: warning: objtool: SUPR0TracerFireProbe+0x7: indirect jump found in RETPOLINE build
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o: warning: objtool: supdrvTracerProbeFireStub+0x0: 'naked' return found in RETHUNK build
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/initterm-r0drv-linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mp-r0drv-linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mpnotification-r0drv-linux.o
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/process-r0drv-linux.o
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemObjNativeLockUser’:
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1228:18: error: too many arguments to function ‘get_user_pages’
  1228 |             rc = get_user_pages(R3Ptr,                  /* Where from. */
       |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 In file included from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/the-linux-kernel.h:102,
                  from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:31:
 ./include/linux/mm.h:2430:6: note: declared here
  2430 | long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
       |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1261:33: error: passing argument 6 of ‘get_user_pages_remote’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  1261 |                                 papVMAs                 /* vmas */
       |                                 ^~~~~~~
       |                                 |
       |                                 struct vm_area_struct **
 ./include/linux/mm.h:2400:33: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘struct vm_area_struct **’
  2400 |                            int *locked);
       |                            ~~~~~^~~~~~
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1245:18: error: too many arguments to function ‘get_user_pages_remote’
  1245 |             rc = get_user_pages_remote(
       |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 ./include/linux/mm.h:2397:6: note: declared here
  2397 | long get_user_pages_remote(struct mm_struct *mm,
       |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1304:39: error: assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’
  1304 |                 papVMAs[rc]->vm_flags |= VM_DONTCOPY | VM_LOCKED;
       |                                       ^~
   CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/rtStrFormatKernelAddress-r0drv-linux.o
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemObjNativeMapUser’:
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1774:35: error: assignment of read-only member ‘vm_flags’
  1774 |                     vma->vm_flags |= VM_DONTEXPAND | VM_DONTDUMP;
       |                                   ^~
 cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
 make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o] Error 1
 make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.o: warning: objtool: VBoxHost_RTR0MemKernelCopyTo+0x13: redundant CLD
 /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.o: warning: objtool: VBoxHost_RTR0MemKernelCopyFrom+0x13: redundant CLD
 make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:488: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv] Error 2
 make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic/Makefile:2037: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build] Error 2
 make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
 make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic'
DKMSKernelVersion: 6.5.0-14-generic
Date: Sun Jan 14 18:03:14 2024
DuplicateSignature: dkms:virtualbox-dkms:6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1:/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:1228:18: error: too many arguments to function ‘get_user_pages’
Package: virtualbox-dkms 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1
PackageVersion: 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1
SourcePackage: virtualbox
Title: virtualbox-dkms 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1: virtualbox kernel module failed to build
```

---

I follow the instruction in the link you provide but still it could not install Vrtualbox.
See below error:

```
julio@Spike:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-7.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kbuild libgsoap-2.8.117 liblzf1 module-assistant virtualbox-source
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  virtualbox-7.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 92,7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 222 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy/contrib amd64 virtualbox-7.0 amd64 7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy [92,7 MB]
Fetched 92,7 MB in 2s (41,2 MB/s)         
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 276471 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-7.0_7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-7.0 (7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy) ...
Setting up libqt5x11extras5:amd64 (5.15.3-1) ...
Setting up virtualbox-7.0 (7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy) ...
addgroup: The group `vboxusers' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
Setting up libsdl-ttf2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.11-6) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1) ...
Removing old virtualbox-6.1.38 DKMS files...
Deleting module virtualbox-6.1.38 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.38 DKMS files...
Building for 6.5.0-14-generic
Building initial module for 6.5.0-14-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.38/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Now it is an udate for virtualbox this should fix the build issue. `apt-cache policy virtualbox
 apt-cache policy virtualbox
virtualbox:
  Installed: 6.1.48-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.22.04.1
  Candidate: 6.1.48-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.22.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 6.1.48-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.22.04.1 500 (phased 20%)
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     6.1.32-dfsg-1build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages
`